# package car unable to load, wrong version of nlme

Tags: r, nlme, r-car

When I try to load the 'car' package I get this error:

```
library(car)

Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'nlme' 3.1-122 is already loaded, but >= 3.1.123 is required
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'car'
```

But when I run `update.packages()` there is nothing to update. I'm using MRO 3.2.3 if that matters.

Comment: The required version might not be available for your version of R?

Comment: The problem seems to be that somehow an old version of `nlme` is part of r-base and is loaded instead of the new version which would be normally loaded if you just load `nlme` via `library()`. One solution could be to load `nlme` before manually when the wrong version is not loaded yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it simply by installing `nlme_3.1-123.tar.gz`    from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nlme/

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate cause of your problem is most likely that MRO [defaults to a static repository](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/faq/#static-repos):

> By default, Microsoft R Open offers its users predictability using a static CRAN snapshot date. For example, the CRAN repository for Microsoft R Open 3.2.3 is configured to point to a snapshot date of Jan 1, 2016. Consequently, with Microsoft R Open 3.2.3 you'll always get packages as they were at midnight UTC on Jan 1, 2016 by default whenever you use install.packages.
>
> Using a fixed CRAN repository snapshot means that every user of Microsoft R Open has access to the same set of CRAN package versions. This makes sharing R code that relies on R packages easier, and reduces the chance of incompatible R packages being installed on the same system. Learn more about fixed CRAN repository snapshots.

Try

```
install.packages("nlme",repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
```

or possibly

```
install.packages("nlme",repos="http://cran.r-project.org",type="binary")
```

(if you get a `type == "both" cannot be used ...` error).

Another possible source of problems with new versions of *recommended* packages is that one may have the old version installed in a system-level package directory, while the new version is installed in a user-level directory; check the results of

```
sapply(.libPaths(),packageVersion,pkg="nlme")
```

and consider adding something like `lib=.libPaths()[2]` to your `install.packages()` call.