# unable to load caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

```
library(caret)
```

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : namespace ‘nlme’ 3.1-121 is already loaded, but >= 3.1.123 is required
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.2.4 
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’

Comment: Possible duplicate of [package car unable to load, wrong version of nlme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469385/package-car-unable-to-load-wrong-version-of-nlme)

Comment: i have installed 3.1.126 nlme but still it throws the same error

Comment: maybe you could provide your sessionInfo()

Comment: i installed freshly and now its working .. Thanks for your support